# Swapping indices

Tags: tensor-calculus

I have a tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ that looks like this:

```
T^mu,nu = {{2,0,1,-1},{1,0,-3,2},{-1,1,0,0},{2,1,-1,2}}
```

I want to find $T^{\nu\mu}$.

If I swap the indices, what does that do to the matrix and for what instances am I able to say $T^{\mu\nu} = -T^{\nu\mu}$? I don't think that would work for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Little correction: the matrix itself is $T$. So
$$ T = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
     2&0&1&-1 \\1&0&-3&2 \\ -1&1&0&0 \\ 2&1&-1&2
  \end{pmatrix} 
$$
On the other hand, $T^{\mu \nu}$ is the element of the matrix at the row $\mu$ and column $\nu$ (e.g. $T^{23} = -3$).

Now for the question, the matrix whose elements are the same as $T$ but with indices swapped is the transpose of $T$, denoted by $T^T$. We swap the rows with the columns, so e.g. $(T^T)^{32} = T^{23} = -3$. For this matrix,

$$ T^T = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
     2&1&-1&2 \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 1&-3&0&-1 \\ -1&2&0&2
  \end{pmatrix} 
$$
From this representation, we can see that $T \neq - T^T$.

Comment: One small correction. The (2 2) part of the transposed matrix should be (2 1). Otherwise, +1.

Comment: Thank you for catching this typo! Just edited.

Comment: Sei benvenuto sempre!!

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have all the components so you also have $T^{\nu\mu}$. You probably mean the transpose of T, but you also have that. Only for $\mu=2$ and $\nu=0$, or vice versa, you have $T^{\mu\nu}=-T^{\nu\mu}$.